# IO Exception while accessing .jar resources

Tags: java, tomcat8

I have a war deployed in tomcat 8. In one of the jar  there is abc.xml file. Now if I am trying to open the input stream  on abc.xml in one of the java class(Example.java) of sample_jar I am getting below exception

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
               at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.ensureOpen(InflaterInputStream.java:67)
       ~[?:1.8.0_102]
               at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:121)
       ~[?:1.8.0_102]
               at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResource$JarInputStreamWrapper.read(AbstractArchiveResource.java:243)
       ~[catalina.jar:?]
               at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager$RewindableInputStream.read(XMLEntityManager.java:2890)
       ~[?:1.8.0_102]
               at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:674)
       ~[?:1.8.0_102]
               at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:148)
       ~[?:1.8.0_102]
               at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:805)
       ~[?:1.8.0_102]
               at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
       ~[?:1.8.0_102]
               at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
       ~[?:1.8.0_102]
               at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
       ~[?:1.8.0_102]
               at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
       ~[?:1.8.0_102]
               at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1892)
       ~[commons-digester-2.1.jar:2.1]
               at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:298)
       ~[jasperreports-6.3.0.jar:6.3.0
```

Now the weird thing is its happening only for first time(once the war is deployed and server starts) on subsequent access it running fine. 
the way I am creating the stream is - 
`InputStream is= Example.class.getResourceAsStream("/abc.xml");`
I would be very thankful if anyone could point out the error.

Edit-1 
Codeblock where I am accessing the file-

```
public class ReportManager {
    public void pageSetting(Map<String, Object> map){
    //code to set report's global info
    }
    public void createReport(String time) {
        try(InputStream coverStream = ReportManager.class.getResourceAsStream("ReportCover");
InputStream reportStream = ReportManager.class.getResourceAsStream("ReportDetail")) {
            JasperReport jasperReport1 = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(coverStream);                   
            JasperReport jasperReport2 = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportStream);
            Map<String, Object> templateParameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            Map<String, Object> coverTemplateParameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            pageSetting(coverTemplateParameters);
            pageSetting(templateParameters);
            JasperPrint jasperPrint1 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport1, coverTemplateParameters,
                    new JREmptyDataSource());
            JasperPrint jasperPrint2 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport2, templateParameters,
                    new JREmptyDataSource());
            List<JasperPrint> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(jasperPrint1);
            list.add(jasperPrint2);
            JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
            exporter.setExporterInput(SimpleExporterInput.getInstance(list));
            exporter.setExporterOutput(
                    new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + File.separator + "Report_Output"+ time + ".pdf"));
            exporter.exportReport();
        } catch (JRException | GeneralException | IOException e2) {
            logger.error("exception in report generation", e2);
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: please post your code block.where you are trying to open that.Also verify where you are closing your stream

Comment: And provide the exact Tomcat version you are using.

Comment: Apache Tomcat Version 8.5.4